# Aligning list contents to center of page

Tags: html, css, wordpress, list, html-lists

I was adding contents to a page of my wordpress site.The content includes a list of services which I need to display in center.I have given

```
<ul style="text-align: center;" >
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li></ul>
```

but the content is going to center of page but not the bullets.This is my [bin](http://jsbin.com/yijakiwi/1/)

Please help me!! Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try to this**

```
li{list-style-position: inside;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qjMHG/)**

Comment: Thanks That worked but the bullets are not aligned straight .Any suggestion please!!

Comment: Than you can used to background image as a bullet